# python-requests and TLS

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

Is it possible to make a request using the requests package using TLS?

when doing:

```
requests.get('someurl')
```

I'm getting:

```
SSLError: [Errno 8] _ssl.c:491: EOF occurred in violation of protocol
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what url you are trying but I hope below helps.

```
In [35]: url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?query=hello&key=xyz'
In [36]: requests.request("GET",url)
Out[36]: <Response [400]>
```

For more documentation please refer [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.request)

Comment: URL is https://www.sam.gov (above method doesn't work). I also did: openssl s_client -tls1 -connect www.sam.gov:443
 and it responded with Protocol  : TLSv1. I assume it has to do with this protocol. I couldn't see that page on firefox either, but could on Chrome. When I went into about:config and turned on TLS, i could see the page